# Slim 3 POST request data not accessable

Tags: php, slim

Using slim 3, I am just trying to post a simple data set and receive it on my server but I can't seem to get the params.

this is my routeing

```
$app->group('/v1', function() use($app) {
  $app->post('/test/create', \MobileV1Controller::class . ':testCreate')
    ->setName('app::testCreate');
}
```

this is my controlling function

```
public function testCreate($req, $res, $args){
    $PostPutVars = $req->getParam('Make');
    return $PostPutVars
}
```

this is the POST body

```
{
"Make" : "Matt"
}
```

Comment: make sure that there is header `Content-type` with value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` or `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$req->getParsedBodyParam('Make')` instead.

> For URL-encoded requests, you can also get a single parameter value,
>   with optional default value if the parameter is missing, using
>   getParsedBodyParam($key, $default = null).

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html